# Is there any app events on Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Android app with several activities and fragments. The app uses SignalR, connected with a .net core backend web app. There are several activities that may require visual modifications depending on the events called by the server. Is there any kind of in-app events that activities may subscribe to on creation that handles those required visual changes?

For example:
I am on an activity that shows 5 images related to a publication, and then the server sends a notification that the publication has been edited so the images have changed. In this case i would want that the SignalR client triggered some in-app event that updates the changed images on created activities of this kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have came up with some kind of solution. I created a class called EventSubscriber that acts exactly how i wanted to.

```
public class EventSubscriber<T> : IEventSubscriber
{
    #region Private members

    private List<Tuple<T, Func<T, bool>>> Subscribtions { get; set; }
    private ConcurrentDictionary<int, Func<T, bool>> WaitingObjectSubscribtions { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public EventSubscriber()
    {
        Subscribtions = new List<Tuple<T, Func<T, bool>>>();
        WaitingObjectSubscribtions = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Func<T, bool>>();
    }

    #region Subscribe
    public void Subscribe(T adapter, Func<T, bool> function)
    {
        lock (Subscribtions)
        {
            Subscribtions.Add(new Tuple<T, Func<T, bool>>(adapter, function));
        }
    }
    public int Subscribe(Func<T, bool> function)
    {
        lock (WaitingObjectSubscribtions)
        {
            int id = WaitingObjectSubscribtions.Count;
            WaitingObjectSubscribtions.TryAdd(id, function);
            return id;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Unsubscribe
    public void UnSubscribe(Tuple<T, Func<T, bool>> item)
    {
        lock (Subscribtions)
        {
            Subscribtions.Remove(item);
        }
    }
    public void UnSubscribe(int id)
    {
        lock (WaitingObjectSubscribtions)
        {
            Func<T, bool> func;
            WaitingObjectSubscribtions.TryRemove(id, out func);
        }

    }
    public void UnSubscribeAll()
    {
        lock (Subscribtions)
        {
            Subscribtions.Clear();
        }
        WaitingObjectSubscribtions.Clear();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Call Subscribed
    public void CallSubscribed()
    {
        lock (Subscribtions)
        {
            foreach (var item in Subscribtions)
            {
                (var adapter, var function) = item;
                if (!function(adapter))
                {
                    Log.Debug("[EventSubscriber]", "Failed to notify adapter, will be automatically unsubscribed from this event");
                    UnSubscribe(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void CallSubscribedWith(T adapter)
    {
        foreach (var id in WaitingObjectSubscribtions.Keys)
        {
            var function = WaitingObjectSubscribtions[id];
            try
            {
                if (!function(adapter))
                {
                    Log.Debug("[EventSubscriber]", "Failed to execute function");
                    UnSubscribe(id);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Log.Debug("[EventSubscriber]", "Failed to execute function");
                UnSubscribe(id);
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

To manage several EventSubscribed used in-app i created a static class Accessible to every Activity or Fragment which contains all the needed events:

```
public static class EventBoard
{
    #region Products and Favorites
    public static EventSubscriber<SwipeRefreshLayout> FinishedLoadingProducts = new EventSubscriber<SwipeRefreshLayout>();
    public static EventSubscriber<List<Product>> SuccessfullyLoadedProducts = new EventSubscriber<List<Product>>();
    public static EventSubscriber<RecyclerView.Adapter> UnsuccessfullyLoadedProducts = new EventSubscriber<RecyclerView.Adapter>();

    //Search
    public static EventSubscriber<SwipeRefreshLayout> FinishedLoadingProductsForSearch = new EventSubscriber<SwipeRefreshLayout>();
    public static EventSubscriber<RecyclerView.Adapter> SuccessfullyLoadedProductsForSearch = new EventSubscriber<RecyclerView.Adapter>();
    public static EventSubscriber<RecyclerView.Adapter> UnsuccessfullyLoadedProductsForSearch = new EventSubscriber<RecyclerView.Adapter>();
    public static EventSubscriber<RecyclerView.Adapter> SearchNotFound = new EventSubscriber<RecyclerView.Adapter>();

    //favorites
    public static EventSubscriber<LocalProduct> ConfirmNewFavoriteEvent = new EventSubscriber<LocalProduct>();
    public static EventSubscriber<LocalProduct> ConfirmRemoveFavoriteEvent = new EventSubscriber<LocalProduct>();
    public static EventSubscriber<LocalProduct> NewFavoriteEvent = new EventSubscriber<LocalProduct>();
    public static EventSubscriber<LocalProduct> RemoveFavoriteEvent = new EventSubscriber<LocalProduct>();
    public static EventSubscriber<List<LocalProduct>> SetFavoritesEvent = new EventSubscriber<List<LocalProduct>>();
    #endregion
}
```

So basically if a new activity is created it can subscribe to an EventSubscriber of its preference. Moreover, it can provide a function that receives any kind of object so it can be as flexible as it can.

The only thing that raise my concern, be sure you unsubscribe your events when the activity or the fragment View is destroyed because they can be a good source of memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please accept your answer after two days.

Comment: I just wanted to help whoever got this problem too! Ty for your support

Answer (score 0):

To communicate with the real-time server, you would have to use methods from the server's package. From researching, you can use the `HubConnection.On` method. Signalr registers the send and receive methods when you built the hub:

```
public class MyHub : Hub{
    public async Task Send(string user, string message){
        // Receive is the name of the listener method
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("Receive", user, message); 
    }
}
```

Then, in your Android activities, you can register to the `HubConnection` (assuming you've sent the message about the edited image) of your listener method using the `On` method:

```
    myHubConnection.On<string, string>("Receive", (user, message) => 
    {
        /* change UI here */
    });
```

Comment: Yes, that is indeed how SignalR works, but then my question is again is there any kind of in-app events that could be use to trigger UI changes on several existing Activities prior subscribed to this event on creation